# How to override supersized.shutter.css

Tags: hooks, theming

I'm not the best in php manipulation that's why I'm asking.

```
function supersized_libraries_info() {
  $libraries['supersized'] = array(
    'title' => 'Supersized',
    'website' => 'http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/',
    'download url' => 'https://github.com/f3ndot/supersized/tree/3718ae83f0945e327cc09530b959c5a8b049871f',
    'version arguments' => array(
      'file' => 'slideshow/js/supersized.3.2.8.min.js',
      'pattern' => '/Version : (\d+)/',
      'lines' => 4,
    ),
    'files' => array(
      'js' => array(
        'slideshow/js/jquery.easing.min.js',
        'slideshow/js/supersized.3.2.8.min.js',
        'slideshow/theme/supersized.shutter.min.js',
      ),
      'css' => array(
        'slideshow/theme/supersized.shutter.css',
        'slideshow/css/supersized.css',
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $libraries;
}
```

That's the all code of supersized_libraries_info() function. I wan't to hook that using hook system so for my theme it suppost to be
mytheme_supersized_libraries_info() right?

Then I wan't to just edit css location so that supersized.shutter.css will be in placed in my theme location.

(My code!)

```
function koko_supersized_libraries_info($variables) {
  $libraries['supersized'] = array(
    'files' => array(
        'css' => array(
        path_to_theme() + '/css/supersized.shutter.css',
        'slideshow/css/supersized.css',
      ),
    ),
  );
```

I just want to edit the css property of that object. I don't know how to get to there.
Mine edit just doesn't work at all (nothing happends).

I want to clear css array and then set mine values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To alter the value returned from an implementation of [`hook_libraries_info()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!libraries!libraries.api.php/function/hook_libraries_info/7), a module or a theme needs to implement [`hook_libraries_info_alter()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!libraries!libraries.api.php/function/hook_libraries_info_alter/7). As with other alter hooks, there isn't a way to override the value returned from a specific module, so the hook name is the usual one: `modulename_library_info_alter()` or `themename_library_info_alter()`.

As side note, you code contains also an error: The parameter is `$variables`, but the code is using `$libraries`.

Answer (score 0):

Like `@kiamlaluno` said, you need to implement `hook_libraries_info_alter()`; however, you should change your code too into something like this:

```
function koko_libraries_info_alter(&$libraries)
{
   if( isset( $libraries['supersized']))
      $libraries['supersized']['files']['css'][] = 
    path_to_theme().'css/something.css';
}
```

This way you only insert an additional CSS at the bottom of the library CSS files, and if the library changes its filenames, or (more likely) add more files, you wont need to change your hook as well. Note that `$libraries` is passed by reference.

You only ensure that your custom CSS is always the last to be valued.